# MailKit on Apache/CentOS not connecting to Gmail SMTP

Tags: c#, apache, asp.net-core, centos7, mailkit

On my .Net Core Application that is Deployed on Apache/CentOS

```
public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
        var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
        bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = message;

        emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("emailuser", "email@gmail.com"));
        emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", email));
        emailMessage.Subject = subject;
        emailMessage.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody ();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate("email@gmail.com", "Password");

                client.Send(emailMessage);
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Every time I try to send an Email using this code, I get the following message.

```
502 Proxy Error

Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /Account/ForgotPassword.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

The Website on the Apache server has SSL Configured.

Im totally at a Quandry. Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you catch/log an exception?

Comment: On Visual Studio, I dont get any exceptions thrown at me. Only when it is on the server does it give me an issue. And I haven't seen any exceptions in the server logs. That is, if I am looking at the right logs.

Comment: I suppose you can use console logger on linux and pipe the console output to a file as a workaround or use one of the community providers listed here https://github.com/aspnet/Logging

Comment: Port 465 is an SSL-wrapped port which means you need to use SslOnConnect, not StartTls.

Comment: Did that, but its still not working. Is there something on the server side that could be preventing the Website from connecting to the External Gmail SMTP?

Comment: Well, your error looked related to some sort of proxy. That could prevent MailKit from connecting. You might need to create your own Socket and connect via the proxy and then pass that socket off to MailKit's `Connect(Socket, ...)` method.